# Getting currentSelectedGameObject doesn't stop firering

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I looked around on how to get the name of a button that was pressed on a canvas, while everything works fine regarding the "getting the name"
a problem accures that this event never stops.

---

So I tried to set the "buttonPressed" to null after getting the name which didn't work.

I also tried to set the es.currentSelectedGameObject to null which I am not allowed to (Should have known that, but worth a try)

I also searched this stackoverflow for solutions but I sadly couldn't find something that solved my problem.

---

```
 void Update()
{
    buttonPressed = es.currentSelectedGameObject;

    if (buttonPressed != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(buttonPressed.name);
        buttonPressed = null;
    } else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

---

So what i want is something like

I click on a button and once the console shows 
"[time] NAME_OF_BUTTON"

what I currently get is a never ending stream of

"[time] NAME_OF_BUTTON"

Thanks in adance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This triggers on all the updates. You can either cancel the selection using `es.SetSelectedGameObject(null);` or use a flag property e.g. `recentlySelected` that is set to `true` only when a game object is selected, and set it to `false` inside the condition. i.e.

```
if (buttonPressed != null && recentlySelected)
{
    Debug.Log(buttonPressed.name);
    buttonPressed = null;
    recentlySelected = false;
}
// Also, else is unnecessary.
```

Comment: oh, sorry, I should have looked closer and noticed the "SetSelectedGameObject" myself. Thank you for pointing it out! :)

I now use this method and it works, would you say this is okay or should i use the flag option for some better reason?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Not sure. Depends on what you want to do. If you want the selected object to stay selected for some reason after writing its name, you may need the flag option.